# How do I change the default jetty port using dockerized jetty

Tags: docker, jetty

I am running jetty from a docker-composer.yml file.  I had changed the port mapping like this:

```
services:
  web:
    image: jetty
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
```

This does not change the port that jetty starts up on.  How do I go about doing this from a dockerized jetty?

Comment: Do you want to connect to jetty on 8000 port instead of standart 8080?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default jetty runs on port `8080`. So you compose file should be

```
services:
  web:
    image: jetty
    ports:
     - "8000:8080"
```

This maps port `8080` from inside the container to port `8000` on your host. Though you should not need to run jetty on port 80 inside the container. But if you still need to for some reason then you need to use the jetty config options using `JAVA_OPTIONS`

```
services:
  web:
    image: jetty
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Djetty.port=80"
    ports:
     - "8000:80"
```

So port `80` inside the container and port `8000` on your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps unrelated, yet helpful:
I had a similar issue in a `Dockerfile` and I chose to override the default jetty port in jetty-http.xml (located in `/usr/local/jetty/etc`) by rewriting the file:

```
FROM jetty:10-....
COPY jetty-http.xml /usr/local/jetty/etc
COPY target/some-war.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT.war
...
```